# Load data first before AuthGuard called in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, auth-guard

I am currently implementing Auth guard in my routes. I want to load data first before auth guard being called. Currently I am doing this.

In my *auth-guard.service.ts* I have this.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if ( this.authService.isLoggedIn() ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And in my *auth.service.ts*

```
 export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  
  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.getUser() !== null;
  }

  setSession(userId: string) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
  }

  getUser() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('userId');
  }

}
```

And in my routes I am calling Auth guard and DataResolver

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    resolve: {
      data: DataResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: UserDashboardComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Dashboard',
        },
      }
    ]
  ]
```

*DataResolver*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataResolver {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  resolve() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((data) => {
      const userId = data.userId;
      if (userId) {
        this.authService.setSession(userId);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Why it is still calling the auth guard first. What I want to to call the DataResolver first before the auth guard.

Comment: When both guard and resolvers are specified, the resolvers are not executed until all guards have run and succeeded. https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#description

Comment: thanks for the meantime I was doing it in every parent component I am checking if user is logged else logout.